# TextBlock Databinding Error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, binding

Class File:

```
public class User
 {
   public string user { get; set; }
 }
```

XML for the TextBlock:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
    <StackPanel x:Name="Stak" Orientation="Vertical" Width="0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" Width="443" Margin="0,0,-443,0" FontSize="22"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="UserText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding User}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="443" Margin="0,0,-443,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="23"/>
    </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

C# code to load text:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream readName = store.OpenFile("/User Information/UserName.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (StreamReader contactName = new StreamReader(readName))
  {
    var name = contactName.ReadLine();
    var Load = new User();
    Load.user = name;
  }
```

So Basically what this is supposed to do is when the app loads, it reads a file from the User Information folder and is meant to add it to the TextBlock text. Because I cant access the TextBlock since it's inside a Pivot Datatemplate, I've binded it.

Once the App is done reading the file it's meant to add whatever is inside the `name` into the textblock but it doesn't do it.

Comment: [How to: Create a Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838207(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: @Ahmed.C, does `<TextBlock .. Text="{Binding}"/>` displays type name?

Comment: @dkozl what do you mean?

Comment: Do you see anything? If your binding context is fine `Text="{Binding}"` should call `ToString()` on your object which be default will return class name, something like `MyNamespace.User`

Comment: When I run the app, the textblock is empty. I'm trying to get the TextBlock called "UserText" to display the text, not the one abouve just so you know.

Comment: Second binding won't work because property name is `user` and you bind to `User`. Property names are case sensitive. But if both `TextBlock` are empty this would suggest binding context is not set to  instance of `User` or any other object. How do you set `DataContext`? You need to show more code.

Comment: I haven't set the DataContext. Also this Textblock is inside the MainPivots DataTemplate. Would there be a way to access it and just use it directly? wouldn't it be much more easier

Comment: Much easier will be doing it by binding and not accessing it directly which is way more complicated. Like I said you need to show more relevant code/XAML as first `TextBlock` inside that `StackPanel` should give you some value. Also are you sure it's not because of right margin which you set to -443 which is rather high and may just put your `TextBlock` of view. I would suggest to leave basic `TextBlock` only with `Text` binding and only when you know it works make it look like you want

Comment: @dkozl Here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82716142/Binding%20Sample/PivotApp1.rar A quick sample on where I'm stuck at.

Comment: Ignore those errors. This is from the default PivotApp where I had to delete unnecessary items.

Comment: after `Load.user = name;` try calling `this.DataContext = Load;` and see if then it will display something

Comment: Nope. Still empty? I should try Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and see if that helps.